# Should we diversify answers on most popular questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, statistics

Most of the questions on our site are usually found using a search engine. It's often good to have multiple answers on one question. 3 answers per question is good, only 1 answer per question needs some work. On a healthy site, questions receive multiple answers and the best answer is voted to the top.

The current side-wide answer rate is **1.4**, which really needs some work. Let's start with the site's most popular questions?

## Popularity by vote score

- [How do I backup my ether accounts?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/108/87/) (11 votes, 714 views, 1 answer)
- [How do you delete/remove/hide contracts from Ethereum Wallet (aka mist)?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2682/87/) (11 votes, 259 views, 1 answer)
- [Struct not being stored in mapping when it contains more than two 'string' properties. Bug?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/900/87/) (11 votes, 222 views, 1 answer)
- [What were the key assumptions and analyses that went into setting Ethereum's gas price?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/324/87/) (11 votes, 174 views, 1 answer)
- [What is a sidechain?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/379/87/) (11 votes, 95 views, 1 answer)
- [How does the solidity optimizer work?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/698/87/) (11 votes, 81 views, 1 answer)
- [What's the best Hardware for Mining Ether?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2719/87/) (9 votes, 623 views, 1 answer)
- [Where do contract event logs get stored in the Ethereum architecture?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1302/87/) (9 votes, 244 views, 1 answer)
- [What is the "difficulty bomb" and what is the goal of it?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/323/87/) (9 votes, 168 views, 1 answer)

Find 493 more on the [data explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/ethereum/query/433545/find-high-voted-unanswered-questions).

## Popularity by view count

- [What is Geth's "fast" sync, and why is it faster?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1161/87/) (2910 views, 15 votes, 1 answer)
- [Help with very slow mist sync](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/603/87/) (2054 views, 4 votes, 1 answer)
- [How do I check my mining hashrate?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1586/87/) (1918 views, 3 votes, 1 answer)
- [How to Mine Ether and use Ethereum on Windows?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/110/87/) (1474 views, 6 votes, 1 answer)
- [What is the current DAG size? When do we expect to hit GPU limits?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/426/87/) (958 views, 3 votes, 1 answer)
- [How long does it take for the ethereum blockchain to synchronize?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1312/87/) (957 views, 2 votes, 1 answer)
- [How to sell ETH for USD or EUR?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1768/87/) (749 views, 2 votes, 1 answer)
- [How do I backup my ether accounts?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/108/87/) (714 views, 11 votes, 1 answer)
- [How is the Mining Difficulty calculated on Ethereum?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1880/87/) (697 views, 6 votes, 1 answer)
- [What's the best Hardware for Mining Ether?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2719/87/) (623 views, 9 votes, 1 answer)

Find 936 more on the [data explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/ethereum/revision/483850/612828/top-10k-questions-by-view-count-and-low-answer-rate-questions-only).

Should we diversify answers on most popular questions? Experts wanted!

Answer (score 2):

I always thought of StackExchange as a unopinionated Q&A site. That means one is encouraged to formulate a rather objective question of general interest, instead of subjective or helpdesk support questions. Not "Do you think PoS is a good thing?" or "Help, I lost my wallet in Mist".

Generalistic, precise and objective questions gravitate towards *one* answer if the answer is correct. I do not see it as a bug but as a feature.

If you are not convinced, consider Stackoverflow, clearly the ripest Q&A site, has an [answer rate](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/info?site=stackoverflow) of **1.61**. So we are not *that* far away.

Said that, I think that some of the popular questions could be improved ("How to sell ETH for USD or EUR?") both in Q as in A. I certainly volunteer to help in the coming days.